# react-facebook-login button style

Tags: css, reactjs, facebook-login

I am using facebook login at my login page, my website is fully responsive, but my facebook login button is not responsive. (i.e when i am using small screen size, facebook login button should change it's with)
Please refer images below:

1) Normal case:

[image]

2) When Screen is resized to pixels less than 399 (screen width < 400)
[image]

3) How i want it to be (in resized browser on PC, or on mobile)

[image]

My react code is:

```
<div style={{display: 'flex',flexWrap: 'wrap' }} >                           
    <FacebookLogin
        appId={facebookAppId}
        autoLoad={false}
        fields="name,email,picture"
        callback={this.props.SocialSignUp}
        cssClass="btnFacebook"
        icon={<i className="fa fa-facebook" style{{marginLeft:'5px'}}>
        </i>}
        textButton = "&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign In with Facebook"                                                                
        />
        <GoogleLogin
            clientId={googleClientId}
            onSuccess={this.props.SocialSignUp}
            onFailure={this.props.SocialSignUp}
            className="btnGoogle"
        >
            <i className="fa fa-google-plus" style={{ marginLeft: 
            '5px' }}/> 
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign In with Google</span>                                                               
        </GoogleLogin>
</div>
```

My CSS is

```
.btnFacebook { 
  width: 165px;
  height:35px;  
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #3b5998;
  color:white;
  border:0px transparent;  
  text-align: center;
  margin:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btnGoogle { 
  margin:5px;
  width: 165px;
  height:35px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #db3236;
  color:white;
  border:0px transparent;
  text-align: center;
}
.btnFacebook:hover {
  background: #3b5998;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.btnGoogle:hover {
  background: #db3236;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 399px) {
  .btnFacebook,.btnGoogle{
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

Please note that I am using **react-facebook-login** package for rendering **facebook** button and **react-google-login** package for rendering **google** button.

Help Please!!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simplified example using [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)

It's using your css and resizing the way it should.

You can copy/paste this Component and import it into your app maybe it helps figuring out your problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    @media only screen and (max-width : 399px) {
        width: 10%
    }
`

const BtnFacebook = styled.button`
    width: 165px;
    height:35px;  
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #3b5998;
    color:white;
    border:0px transparent;  
    text-align: center;
    margin:5px;
    display: inline-block;

    &:hover{
        background: #3b5998;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
`;
const BtnGoogle = styled.button`
    margin:5px;
    width: 165px;
    height:35px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #db3236;
    color:white;
    border:0px transparent;
    text-align: center;

    &:hover{
        background: #3b5998;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
`
class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }} >
                <Wrapper>
                    <BtnFacebook >
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;Sign In with Facebook
                        </BtnFacebook >
                    <BtnGoogle>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;Sign In with Google
                        </BtnGoogle >
                </Wrapper>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems working for me. Just did a work around on your code. Tell the exact error. It would be helpful. Here I attached the output.
[image]

[image]

Comment: open the code in mobile view, or resize your browser window and check the case 2. 
The code is not responsive

Comment: Kindly check the attachment.